# Insert data into master -details table using oracle procedure/Functions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a GUI (Master-Details). I want to insert the =data from corresponding fields to two of tables using a Procedure or function.

How can I pass the multiple rows to Procedure/Function to insert the data in both the table in transacted form.

I don't want to fire insert statement from GUI/

Comment: Please clarify "multiple rows".  One master row and one detail row?  One master row and several detail rows?  Several master rows and several sets of detail rows?  Is one master and no detail rows a possibility?

Comment: What GUI tool are you using? Are you using Oracle Forms?

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle Forms 11g.

Comment: OraNob, Can you please provide me developer book for oracle forms? I googled for it but could not any  book with practical scenarios.

Comment: I want to base a datablock on procedure.  I want to pass a recordgroup or sysrefcursor to a procesdure so that I can execute master-detail queries in single transaction. I have created a procedure with some arguments and sysrefcursor as a parameter. now how can I pass the values from detail datablock as sysrefcursor to a procedure. and also how can I fill the values into datablock.